# Statement Passed to Mysql Database not filling DataTable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
 dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN " & startDate & " AND " & endDate & ""
```

When i execute this statement in NaviCat it does not return any values either. Tho the values do exist on the 19th and 22nd of June in 2015.
am i sending the query wrong???

Upon debugging the query is sent as follows.

```
select * from table where date between 6/1/2015 and 6/31/2015
```

Comment: try change the date to 6-1-2015 and 6-31-2015

Comment: don't you need to use `#` around dates?

Comment: what is the column type for `date` (which is a rather bad name for a column)?

Comment: The dates are in the database as m/dd/yyyy i attempted the - vs / and no luck =/

@ t.s. im not sure what you mean

Comment: @ Plutonix This column type is varchar because of the application its used for this makes it much simpler

Comment: "The dates are in the database as m/dd/yyyy" - you mean, dates are stored as strings?

Comment: If the dates are stored as strings (and with that format) then every search query on these fields are doomed. Plain and simple

Comment: What would your solution be steve?

Comment: solution is to store dates as `Date`, then you can use `between, <, > ` etc...If you store as string , you db engine comparing strings, like `abc`, it doesn't know what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the comparisons to operate on "date" values, the way you expect, you need to convert the strings into `DATE` values.

The problem in your query is that the the comparison is being done in a *numeric* context, rather than on `DATE` values. Your query is roughly equivalent to

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE date BETWEEN 0.0029776674937965260545905707 AND 0.000096053790122469
```

That is, the literals in the "between" comparison are evaluating to numeric values (e.g. six divided by thirty-one divided by two thousand fifteen). To illustrate this, consider the output from this:

```
 SELECT '6/12/2015'
      , 6/1/2015
      , 6/31/2015
      , '6/12/2015' BETWEEN 6/1/2015 AND 6/31/2015 
      , '6/12/2015' BETWEEN 5.9 AND 6.2
```

---

If you wrap the literals in quotes (as suggested in another answer) will also *not* give expected behavior.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE date BETWEEN '6/1/2015' AND '6/31/2015'
```

The problem with numeric evaluation and comparison is fixed, but now the comparison will be done in *string* context. This will return *some* date values in the month of June, but it will also **exclude** some values that we would (reasonably) expect to be returned, such as **'6/4/2015'**. As a demonstration, consider:

```
 SELECT '6/4/2015' BETWEEN '6/1/2015' AND '6/31/2015'
```

---

MySQL has builtin datatypes designed for handling "datetime" type values... **`DATE`**, **`DATETIME`** and **`TIMESTAMP`**. These datatypes make working with "date" and "datetime" values easy, and make comparisons simple.

---

**Use DATE datatype and STR_TO_DATE function**

To get the comparisons done as "date" values, convert the column value and the literals into **`DATE`** datatype.

The MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function will convert a string into a `DATE`, based on the specified format.

To get "date" comparisons to work "correctly" on string values, you could do something like this:

```
     SELECT t.* 
       FROM table t 
      WHERE STR_TO_DATE( t.date     ,'%m/%d/%Y')
    BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE( '6/1/2015' ,'%m/%d/%Y')
        AND STR_TO_DATE( '6/3/2015' ,'%m/%d/%Y')
```

Note the single quotes around the literals, those are needed for those literals to be seen as strings, and not numeric expressions. The real trick is the MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function.

---

Note that MySQL cannot make effective use of an index to satisfy the predicate, the `STR_TO_DATE` function has to be evaluated for *every* row in the table.

If this column was defined as `DATE` datatype, then we could do the comparison on the bare column, and MySQL can make use of a range scan operation on a suitable index.

Comment: Just changed my data type to date

Answer (score 3):

Since your column is `varchar`, you will need to cast it to the correct type if you want comparisons to work correctly.

```
dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('" & startDate & "' as DATE) AND CAST('" & endDate & "' as DATE)"
```

Alternately, since you are using MySQL, you could use the `STR_TO_DATE` function like so:

```
dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('" & startDate & "', '%m/%d/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('" & endDate & "', '%m/%d/%Y')"
```

The main difference between those two is that trying to `CAST` an invalid string into a date will result in an error, while doing the same thing but using `STR_TO_DATE` will substitute `NULL` for the invalid string, which will result in your query returning no rows.

As others have mentioned, you're not doing yourself any favors by storing dates as strings.  In most languages, it is trivially easy to convert a date to a string (i.e., for display purposes), but the inverse is not always true.  Since you are storing dates as strings, the best you will be able to do is to cast and hope that all of your strings are valid dates.

The SQL standard includes data types for dates, and for good reason.  You would be well-advised to use them.

Comment: I was just about to say this

Answer (score -1):

As said by Steve the field type is bad for a date. Anyway Since date type is varchar you might try this:

```
select * from table where date >= '6/1/2015' and date <= '6/31/2015';
```

Comment: This works Perfect! , The software is in testing and the DB is small i might convert to a date type to make anyone looking at it in the future a happy camper. 

Thanks To everyone who added their input!

Comment: This works perfect... only if you consider `'6/4/2015'` to not be included in values between `'6/1/2015'` and `'6/31/2015'`. (It seems very odd that we'd want to exclude the 4th through the 9th of the month.)

Comment: Thats true spencer: 
MSSQL -> select * from table where date >= try_convert(datetime2, '06/01/2015') and date <= try_convert(datetime2, '06/30/2015')
                                                                                                                     MySQL-> SELECT * FROM table  WHERE Date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('6/1/2015', %m/%d/%y) and STR_TO_DATE('6/30/2015',%m/%d/%y)

Comment: @WallyB will figure it out eventually....maybe.  Kind of funny how he accepted the only downvoted answer as the correct one.

Comment: funny - maybe He didn't try entering the other date string and test that query

Comment: Why does this exclude the 4th to the 9th of the month?

Comment: It does simple string comparison rather doing the date comparison

Comment: Because a STRING comparison is being done since your values are all strings.  You need to compare them as DATE.